# List of Evergreen Browsers and User Agents

Tags: javascript, browser, microsoft-edge, user-agent

Does anyone know of a list of evergreen browsers and their associated user agents somewhere online? I could not find one. I know it is not foolproof, but I want to do a check of user agents to ensure the end user is utilizing an evergreen browser. We are not going to be supporting IE, so that one is easy since it is not evergreen...my largest concern is Edge. I believe that started out as not being evergreen, but MS made a change to it with a Windows 10 update...making it evergreen. So I want to check user agents to ensure the end users are not using IE or pre-evergreen Edge. That is why I was looking for a list somewhere so I can see what their UA's entail.

Comment: Perhaps you could code a solution based on [browserslist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist)? It's pretty popular. They have a tool called [browserslist-useragent-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist-useragent-regexp) that could generate a RegExp to match the browsers you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there's no official docs about Evergreen Browser list.

I found [this link](https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/what_is_an_evergreen_browser) and I think the explanation is clear:

> The term "evergreen" refers to the release strategy. Evergreen browsers are updated frequently in background, constantly updating their compliance with Web Standards and also adding proprietary features.

I think your point is to detect IE and Edge Legacy (EdgeHTML) which are not evergreen. You can use the code below to detect IE and Edge Legacy using `window.navigator.userAgent`:

```
<script>
    var browser = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (browser.indexOf("edge") > -1 || browser.indexOf("trident") > -1) {
        alert("We don't support IE and Edge Legacy");
    }
</script>
```

In the code above, `edge` is for Edge Legacy (in Edge Chromium, it's `edg`), `trident` is for IE.

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find the information on Edge versus Edge Legacy?

Comment: @ClayHess About Edge user agent, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-string). And there's one sentence in the doc: *Microsoft selected the `Edg` token to avoid compatibility issues that may be caused by using the string `Edge`, which is used by the version of Microsoft Edge based on EdgeHTML*.